# Show if $\cos(\lambda t+U)$ is stationary

Tags: statistics, covariance, stationary-point

Let $X_{t}=\cos(\lambda t+U)$ where $\lambda \in R$ and $U$ is a random variable uniformly distrusted on ($-\pi,\pi$]. Determine the covariance function $\gamma_{X}(t,t+h)=Cov(X_{t},X_{t+1})$. is {$X_{t}$} stationary?

Own work: Ihave been trying to determine the covariance using expected value and the trigonometric addition identity. but don't seem to be getting very far. Thanks for any help

so far i know that the expectation of $EX_{t}=0$ from this the covariance is equal to $E(X_{t}X_{t+h})$
$E(X_{t}X_{t+h})=E(cos(\lambda t +U)cos(\lambda(t+h)+U)$

$=E((\cos(\lambda t)\cos(U)-\sin(\lambda t)\sin(U)(\cos(\lambda (t+h)\cos(U)-\sin(\lambda (t+h))\sin(U)))$

Comment: write down all the components you have done - including the expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\cos(A) \cos(B) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(A-B) + \cos(A+B)\right) $$

Comment: Thanks allot for the help